# Please explain "a-=(a--)-(--a)"

Tags: java, output

Can anyone please help me with this output-

```
a-=(a--)-(--a)
```

when the initial value of a is 6.

The answer upon execution is coming to 4 but according to me it should be -4. I would appreciate it if you could show me step-by-step.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about being unable to use a compiler and a debugger.

Comment: `a--` makes `a` `5` and results in `6`. Then `--a` makes `a` `4` and results in `4`. `a -=` already started with `a` at `6`, `6 - 4` is `2`, and `6 - 2` is `4`. … maybe. Might I advise you to not ever write code like this?

Comment: Can you explain why you would write code like this?

Comment: @devnull he clearly used a compiler to determine that the result is 4, and most debuggers won't let you step less than a statement at a time.

Comment: @immibis Doing such crazy stuff isn't warranted in any case.  If one is doing it, then need to understand it before attempting to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = 6
a -= (a--) - (--a)
```

Equivalent to:

```
a = a - ((a--) - (--a))
```

Right side is evaluated first, left to right:

`a`<sup>1</sup> -> `a--`<sup>2</sup> -> `--a`<sup>3</sup> -> `(a--)-(--a)`<sup>4</sup> -> `a-((a--)-(--a))`
<sup>5</sup>

- Step 1: `a` evaluates to 6.
- Step 2: `a--`; evaluates to 6, `a` becomes 5.
- Step 3: `--a`; evaluates to 4, `a` becomes 4.
- Step 4: `6 - 4`; evaluates to 2.
- Step 5: `6 - (6 - 4)` evaluates to 2.
- Final: `a = 6 - (6 - 4)`; `a` becomes 4.

Comment: *“Step 2: a--; evaluates to 5, a becomes 4.”* Evaluates to 6, a becomes 5, I think…

Comment: In the final step, since `a` is now `4`, why isn't that `a = 4 - (6 - 4)`?

Comment: @ChrisMartin Because the first `a` term was already evaluated to `6` in step 1. I have added labels to the steps in the evaluation order to show that.

Answer (score 1):

Your trouble comes from the order in which values are used in relation to their increment or decrement operators (pre or post).

In a pre-decrement situation where the value is decremented BEFORE the variable `(--a)` the program reduces the value of `a` by one, and THEN uses the value.

In a post-decrement situation where the value is decremented AFTER the variable `(a--)` the program takes the value of `a` and THEN reduces the value by one.

**Your Case**

When a = 6

- a -= (anything) can be written a = a - (anything)

Therefore a = 6 - (anything)

- 6- ( (a--) - (--a) )
- Remember, the value of (a--) is 6, and then it is reduced to 5 for later use
- 6 - (6) - (--a)
- Now a is 5. When we evaluate `(--a)` we reduce the value to 4 and then use that value
- 6 - (6) - (4)
- Then just evaluate
- 6 - (2)
- 4

Answer (score 0):

- The first `a--` does a post decrement which means, there `a` is taken
  as `6` and when `a` is accessed next time, it will be `5`.
- But since
  when a is accessed next time, it is as `--a`, a becomes from `5` to
  `4`.
- Thus `(a--)-(--a)` becomes `(6)-(4)` which is `2`.
- Then, `a-=2`
  is evaluated, and `a` was `6` when `a-=` was evaluated, thus, `6-2` is
  `4`.